# How to get data from each dynamically generated cell in a jQuery Table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to get data from a dynamically generated cell in jQuery table, but always have the same problem, my data is "undefined". Can somebody help me or give any advice?

My code:

```
function loadWeekData() {

    // Append database data here

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/JsonWeekEvents",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (i, val) {
                var trow = $('<tr/>').data("id", val.Id);
                //trow.append('<td>' + val.Id + "&nbsp;" + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td style="padding:5px; width:100px; height:70px"></td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsM" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" id="monVal" class="desc_Num">' + val.Monday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsT" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" class="desc_Num">' + val.Tuesday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsW" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" class="desc_Num">' + val.Wednesday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsTr" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" class="desc_Num">' + val.Thursday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsFr" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" class="desc_Num">' + val.Friday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsSt" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" class="desc_Num">' + val.Saturday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsSu" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" class="desc_Num">' + val.Sunday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td  style="padding:2px; width:100px; height:70px"><a href="#" rel="events-week-edit" class="edit">Edit Week</a></td>');
                tab.append(trow);
            });

            $("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');
            $("#weekEvents").html(tab);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed! Please try again.");
        }
    });
    var tab = $('<table class=MyTable border=1 ></table>');
    var thead = $('<thead></thead>');

    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">FSE' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Monday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Tuesday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Wednesday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Thursday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Friday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Saturday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Sunday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');

    tab.append(thead);

    tab.on("focus", ".tags", function (e) {

        //var prefix = $('.tags').val();

        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetSearchValue",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        search: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {

                                label: item.Title + ', ' + item.Description, value: item.Title,

                                Id: item.Id,
                                Title: item.Title,
                                Description: item.Description,
                                Location: item.Location
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("Error!" + xhr);
                    }
                });

            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var field_id = $(this).closest("div").find(".idEvent");
                field_id.val(ui.item.Id);

            }
        });


    });

    tab.on("click", ".addEvent", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest("div").find(".idEvent").val();
        var field = $(this).closest("div").find(".desc_Num");
        var select = $(this).closest("div").find(".tags");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/AutoEventDetails",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                var res = $('<p>' + data.Title + '<br/>' + data.Description + '<br/>' + data.Location + '</p>');
                field.html(res);
                select.val('');
            }


        });
    });

    tab.on("click", ".edit", function (e) {

        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var id = tr.data("id");
        var div = $(this).closest("div").find("monVal");
        var mon = div.val();

        //var mon = $(this).get(".desc_Num").val();
        //var res = $('');
        //res.append(mon);
        //$("#test").html(res);

        alert("ok" + id + mon );
    });
}
```

In the last "tab.on", I'm trying to get data from "monday" cell, but it's always "undefined"...

Does somebody have an idea?

I just want to get all data from all days to pass it then in an Ajax "POST" function to write it into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this line

```
 var div = $(this).closest("div").find("monVal");
```

into

```
 var div = $(this).closest("div").find("#monVal");
```

as the `<div>` you want to find has the `id` monval.

In addition you have to change

```
 var mon = div.val();
```

into

```
 var mon = div.text();
```

or

```
 var mon = div.html();
```

as a `<div>` element has no value you could get with `val()`.

Comment: its not "undefined" any more, but in alert dialog I can not see the data...

Comment: @Dimitri I have just updated my answer as I spotted a second mistake, please try again with the updated adjustment.

Comment: @Dimitri Glad that I was able to help :)

Comment: somehow, it shows data only from the first row, if I have 2 rows and click on a link for second row I can see data from the right cell, but the from the wrong row, id is right, inbetween...

Comment: @Dimitri Can you make a Fiddle with your code? It's difficult to give any advice based on the code of your question though it should work as you select the closest <tr> based on the edit link that was clicked and select the content based on an id which should be unique.

Comment: @Dimitri It's not possible to give any advice based on this Fiddle as it doesn't contain any edit link or element with the class desc_Num. Isn't it possible to make a Fiddle with the generated HTML?

Comment: I'll try to prepare it and send it than, maybe I'll do it with an array as Database...

Comment: is it possible here to attach some photos? its not really easy to fiddle all my logic from DB XD, maybe it will be more clear with photos

Comment: @Dimitri You could use e.g. imgur.com for sharing photos.

Comment: maybe You it make it more undrstandable https://imgur.com/a/jbQpBJx

Comment: and there is class "desc_Num" in every  throw.append:

Comment: trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsM" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" id="monVal" class="desc_Num">' + val.Monday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');

Comment: @Dimitri But there is no edit link in this table row, is it somewhere else?

Comment: @Dimitri If the edit link is in the same row as the element with the class desc_Num your code should work as expected.

Comment: I also thought that, but somehow it doesnt. I will check it one more time, maybe I've made mistake somewere... anyway thank You :)

Comment: @Dimitri Sorry I can't assist any further, hopefully you'll be able to solve this issue as it's not understandable that it happens at all.